# mindmeld sdk for swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Issue I am facing is with a third party framework: [mindmeld](https://expectlabs.com/public/sdks/ios/mindmeld-ios-sdk.zip)

I want to include it in my swift code base. The framework is written in objective-c.

I added the framework in my list of frameworks but I see errors:

> undef: _utf8_nextCharSafeBody
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_utf8_nextCharSafeBody", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   -[SRWebSocket _innerPumpScanner] in MindMeldSDK(SRWebSocket.o)
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

However, I can include is fine in objective-c code bases. Any clues on why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you forgot to add a Objective-C bridging header file to your project. The bridging header is a c style .h file where you import the Objective-C .h files the linker needs to link the code.. Also make sure you add the bridging header to your project settings under "Build Settings" -> "Objective-C Bridging Header".

Please see the following link for a detailed explanation of bridging headers:
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: The problem was there because I was not adding the libraries in Build Phases under Link Binary with Libraries. But your solution is also partially correct.